# Select elements by HTML5 data attribute in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible to select elements in jQuery by their HTML5 [`data`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) attributes (for example, all `<div>` with `data-role='footer'`)?

Comment: yes you can http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: @Sep - That's actually not "how jQuery would do it", it will hand it off to a `querySelectorAll()` call if possible (and it will with an attribute selector here), not loop through the DOM itself...unless there's no other way (e.g. a custom non-CSS selector used)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can select on a `data-` attribute like any other attribute...using an [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/).  In this case you want the [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), like this:

```
$("div[data-role='footer']")
```

They are handled specially in *consumption* by jQuery, e.g. allowing [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to fetch from them with correct typing...but as far as DOM traversal goes, they're just another attribute, so think of them as such when writing selectors.

Answer (score 9):

```
$('div[data-role="footer"]')
```

This simply uses the the [`attribute-equals-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

There are [several attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) you can use (among the others).

Answer (score 5):

jQuery Mobile recomends the $.fn.jqmData(), for example : $("div:jqmData(role='footer')")

Source: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html

Answer (score 0):

jQuery & Zepto integration: https://github.com/kossnocorp/role