# jQuery get an element by its data-id

Tags: javascript, jquery

Similar to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute-using-jquery), I'm looking to get an element based on it's data-id.

`<a href="#" class="whatever" data-item-id="stand-out">...</a>`

I'm looking to take action on the a tag. It has a shared class amongst many other elements and has no base id, just a data-item-id.

Can the element be found by it's data-item-id or can I only find out what the data-item-id is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select elements by HTML5 data attribute in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993447/select-elements-by-html5-data-attribute-in-jquery)

Comment: For those that arrived here via Google.  Note that the answers here reflect how to get an element by data-item-id and not data-id.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can always use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). The selector itself would look something like:

```
a[data-item-id=stand-out]
```

Comment: Double quotes around (in this case) stand-out are required as per kd12's answer. Note also that this expression will search every a element on the page. If you want to optimize it, you can limit the search using a parent element id or a class.

Answer (score 86):

`$('[data-item-id="stand-out"]')`

Answer (score 25):

This worked for me, in my case I had a button with a data-id attribute:

```
$("a").data("item-id");
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GaSj8/)

Answer (score 23):

Yes, you can find out element by data attribute.

```
element = $('a[data-item-id="stand-out"]');
```