# Jquery selecting element by 'data-id'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Similar to the [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19866509/jquery-get-an-element-by-its-data-id) , I need to get an element based on its `data-id`. 
The problem I encounter is that I  want to retrieve a an a element with a certain `data-id` using a variable.

lets consider the code below:

```
var item_id = 12345;
```

if  I want to get the element that has  the `data-id` with the value of item_id, would I do the following ?

```
$('[data-id=item_id]')
```

This does not work, and I am kind of stuck on how I can get around this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can concatenate the variable using `+`:

```
$('[data-id=' + item_id + ']')
```

Comment: Ok I really feel stupid now that I know its just string concatenation! Thanks a heaps