# click on button based on custom data-id, using console

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs

i have a list of items, each item is a button with a unique `data-id` like this

`<button type="button" class="stuff" data-id="123">`

i need to click on the button using the console

how would i select the button using only it's specific `data-id` (and Click on the button) using only javascript or jQuery, in the console?

the below answer is not a solution, because i cannot use the CSS query selector
[jQuery get an element by its data-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19866509/jquery-get-an-element-by-its-data-id)

Comment: "the below answer is not a solution" - Why did you accept it?

Comment: "the below answer" is referring to the question i linked in my question. the question was similar, and i wanted to demonstrate that i looked through stack exchange before asking my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery, you would do it like so:

```
$("[data-id]") // all elements with data-id
$("button[data-id]") // all buttons with data-id
$("button[data-id]").click() // trigger click
```

Comment: thank you! it worked. stackOverflow doesn't let me upvote your answer

Comment: do you know where in the docs it explains how your answer works? specifically the square brackets?

Comment: No worries!  Yes, indeed, here's a link: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/    You can actually target any attribute on a DOM element this way.

Answer (score 2):

You can select using query selector in javascript

```
document.querySelector('[data-id="123"]').click();
```

Jquery

```
$("[data-id='123']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the `data-id` you're targeting is:

```
const id = `sample`;
```

Then you can enter the above line followed by the following in the console to select it:

```
$(`[data-id="${id}"]`).click();
//OR
$('[data-id]').filter((i,b) => $(b).data('id') === id).click();
```

Comment: Good catch @Taplar. Updated.